# Mnesia fold over records, referencing a second table

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a schema something like this:

```
-record(sale, {
  id,
  price,
  tax,
  sku,
  datetime
})

-record(refund, {
  id,
  sale_id,
  datetime
})
```

There are about 600,000 records in the `sale` table and about 20,000 in the `refund` table.

I need to fold over the data in the sales table, grouping each `sku` with the amount received (`price`) and the amount refunded (by checking `#refund.sale_id`).

Is there an efficient way to do this with Mnesia, that avoid the N+1 query problem where for each `sale` in the fold operation, I need to make a second call the mnesia to see if a refund exists? Some way of doing a naive join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `sale` table `ordered_set`? If yes, you can do merge join as usual. First get all `refund` and sort them by `sale_id`. Then just fold over `sale` and accumulate into dict or ets by `sku` key.

Comment: It is `set`, but I can change to `ordered_set`, since I didn't have a specific reason for using `set` (other than an inkling it may be faster). What do you mean by "do a merge join as usual"? Do I need to read all records into memory first (this may be a problem, due to the size of the table)?

Comment: Ah wait, you've given me some new keywords to help myself with, so don't worry about giving any specific examples yet :) I searched for "mnesia merge join" and found reference to that in `qlc`... I didn't realize query list comprehensions could do joins :)

Comment: I'm still concerned about the memory use though, since the records don't all fit into memory, which is why I was using a fold over just the sales table until I had to factor in refunds.

Comment: Add qlc: Yes there is documented that `qlc` supports merge joins and it can work in his case. You can try.

Comment: Add merge join: To be hones it is not merge join as usual. I'm using this technique so often that I tend to forgot that is not so usual. I try elaborate about it when I will have more time.

Comment: I figured it out from the documentation, thank you. It's a very nice way of querying the data!